# Trying to get the intValue of a textfield's text in the debugger

Tags: objective-c, debugging, lldb

Why can't I print my text field's text's `intValue` in the debugger?

```
Printing description of textField:
<UITextField: 0x8e65550; frame = (87 11; 194 18); text = '2'; autoresize = W+RM+H+BM; tag = 5; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e64040>>
(lldb) po textField.text.intValue
error: property 'text' not found on object of type 'UITextField *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po textField.text
error: property 'text' not found on object of type 'UITextField *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po textField
(UITextField *) $15 = 0x08e65550 <UITextField: 0x8e65550; frame = (87 11; 194 18); text = '2'; autoresize = W+RM+H+BM; tag = 5; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e64040>>
```

Comment: It means that intValue is not a property of text which is a property of UILabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you can use in the debugger isn't always exactly the same as the syntax you'd use in your source, and LLDB is still a work in progress. The double use of dot syntax seems to be confusing it. Try using bracket syntax:

```
(lldb) po [[textField text] intValue]
```

Comment: yes, I was about to post my answer: (lldb) po [textField text]
(id) $24 = 0x088630b0 2. Thanks